# sencha touch2: mouse pointer changes to cursor when hover on button

Tags: button, sencha-touch-2

I noticed some issue with my buttons.
I had created a button and on mouse hover the mouse pointer changes to a cursor.
I know that in mobile we won't be having a cursor so this issue will not be there but i want to know if there is a possible solution for this when testing in browser?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach a CSS rule which sets the cursor.

Comment: i was able to do it using the following css
.mouse-hover
{
    cursor: default;
}
Thanks!